# Spring boot 2.1 + Ignite repository 2.7.0 -workaround for spring data commons issue while using @Query or query methods

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, ignite, spring-data-commons

Hi I'm using Spring boot 2.1.2 and Ignite 2.7.0

I have CRUD Ignite Repository with query methods

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = SmartConstants.IGNITE_ISSUE_DETAILS_CACHE)
public interface IgniteIssueDetailsRepository extends IgniteRepository<IgniteIssueDetails,Long>{

    List<IgniteIssueDetails> findAllByProjectName(String projectName);
    Long countByProjectNameAndResolution(String projectName,String resolution);
    Long countByProjectName(String projectName);
}
```

Error :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query
>   method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy
>   defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!

I understand this is due to spring data commons change from 2.0.X to 2.1.X
but couldn't find a solution for ignite

Ignite 2.7 still have old method definition

```
 @Override protected QueryLookupStrategy getQueryLookupStrategy(final QueryLookupStrategy.Key key,
        EvaluationContextProvider evaluationCtxProvider) {
```

This does not meed with new spring data commons definition

```
@Override
    protected Optional<QueryLookupStrategy> getQueryLookupStrategy(@Nullable Key key,
            QueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider evaluationContextProvider) {
```

I tried including multiple versions of commons but keep getting some other error.

If I use pre-loaded method like findAll() it works fine!!

**Do we have any spring-data-commons version which can help me here :(**

main spring application :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableIgniteRepositories(value="com.fico.ps.smart.model.ignite.repository",queryLookupStrategy = Key.CREATE)
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.fico.ps.smart.model.onboarding.repository")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

my dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring-data</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this error with the following dependency configuraton:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring-data_2.0</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- org.apache.ignite.springdata20.repository.support.IgniteRepositoryFactory depends in 2.0.x -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- This is the latest version in the 2.0.x stream -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.14.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the above issue. This issue is resolved in Apache Ignite 2.8.1 with ignite-spring-data_2.2 dependency.

Please use the below maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring-data_2.2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I can confirm the below combo works fine: Spring Boot-2.3.2 and Apache Ignite (ignite-spring-data_2.2)-2.8.1

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

problem was to support spring boot 2.0.X ignite has special _2.0 spring data library.
it supports only 2.7.0.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring-data_2.0</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

after this query methods work fine :)

Comment: I am using  `ignite-spring-data_2.0 : 2.7.0 ` in my application , i don't have any specific `ecxlusions` mentioned in my `pom.xml` for .`spring-data-commons` jar and in my `dependency-hierarchy` .`spring-data-commons: 2.0.9.Release` is shown as a dependency from   `ignite-spring-data_2.0 : 2.7.0`  . I am still facing the error : `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods`

Answer (score 0):

As Bruce indicated the version 2.0.14.RELEASE of spring-data-commons is the only one that works. I tried this newer version and got the error also!

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring-data_2.0</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Do we have any resolution with Spring 2.1.X version with Ignite 2.7 version. if yes please share.. I am also facing the same issue but its working fine with Spring 2.0.X version